# How to check if UDP port is open?

Tags: networking, command-line

Is it possible, using Linux/Unix commands to check if a UDP port is open on a remote computer, the same way `telnet` works for TCP?

Comment: The question is answered in great detail here: http://serverfault.com/questions/416205/testing-udp-port-connectivity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `nmap` to scan a remote computer.